# Switching between Synchronization and Import in User Profiles Service SharePoint 2013

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, synchronisation, active-directory-import, ups

Is it safely or not to switch between import from AD DS option and synchronization option in order to quickly upload the missing contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you intend to switch, you should be aware of

- Each time you change the sync mechanism from `SharePoint Profile Synchronization` to `Active Directory Import` the user `profile synchronization service` is stopped. You will need to restart it if you have switched again to `SharePoint Profile Synchronization`.

**Advantage to Switch**

- Extremely fast performance than SharePoint Profile Synchronization.
- Very reliable
- Connect to forests with multiple domains
- Windows, FBA and claims are all supported

**Disadvantage**

- Cannot import from any other user repository than AD (no LDAP support)
- Sync is one way from AD into SharePoint

For more Details Check [Active Directory Import for SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013/)